# Basis vectors of a linear space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Knowing that: $$W=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 | x_1+2x_2-x_3+x_4=0 \}$$
Is the basis of this subspace $(-2,1,0,0),(1,0,1,0),(-1,0,0,1)$ If it is true then i need only the simple yes/no answer. If not then further comments would be appreciated.

Comment: nice job. you have the basis right.

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as "THE basis of the subspace". The subspace has many different bases; you have found one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Though the basis could be simpler.

Comment: What does "simpler" mean for you here? Any basis for this subspace will consist of three vectors, each with at least two nonzero entries. No obvious improvement on the OP's basis seems possible.

Comment: True. I apologize for using the wrong word here. I was just thinking that the form of the basis could be more straightforward, such as (1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0).

Comment: x @kkcocoqq: But it can't, not for this subspace. (Well, except if one considers all-positive entries to be "more straightforward" and therefore prefers (1,0,1,0),(0,1,2,0),(0,0,1,1)).